# Binding one column to several textboxes with different values

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I want to bind two textboxes to a single column from the xml file. However, whenever I click save, the textboxes take only the last set of data entered as shown below:

**Before save**

[image: Before save]

**After save**

[image: After save]

How can I bind the textboxes in a way that will retain the different data input into each of them.

This is the code I have:

```
Public Class Form1

Private xmlDataBind As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\xmlData.xml"
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(xmlDataBind) = True Then

        DataSet1.ReadXml(xmlDataBind)

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub InfoBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InfoBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    InfoBindingSource.EndEdit()
    DataSet1.WriteXml(xmlDataBind)


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It's a 1 to 1 ratio when you bind an object.  A single object can't be split into 2 and expect to act as 1.

Comment: Seems like using `DataGridView` instead of textboxes will be easier approach

Comment: I really don't want to replace the textboxes.

Comment: That's is a reason why you "waste" time in asking for "hacky" workarounds :)

Comment: The reason I want the textboxes is because the value of one textbox is going to affect the value of others programatically when I finish writing the program. Is there a way to refer to each cell of a datagrid programatically?